# Package caption Error: The nonfloat package is incompatible to the(caption) so try \usepackage{caption}[=v1] instead. \begin{document}

Tags: floats, errors, captions, subcaption, incompatibility

When I run textstudio I get the following error message   (Package caption Error: The nonfloat package is incompatible to the(caption) so try \usepackage{caption}[=v1] instead. \begin{document}) , the files where running fine in the old versions of textstudio and MikTex I just got a new laptop and installed newer versions and this is the error I'm getting. I'm not a guru in Latex can anyone please help I have no idea what is the issue that is causing these errors.

[image]

Comment: I've never heard of the `nonfloat` package before, and if it doesn't work with the latest version of `caption` then I suspect it is best avoided. I would use the `float` package which provides the `[H]` option to create nonfloating figures and tables.

Comment: Thanks @IanThompson I will continue to use Textstudio and MikTex from my other laptop as you have suggested.

Comment: That's not what I meant. I meant stop using the `nonfloat` package. If it's not compatible with `caption` (which is pretty standard), then it's probably obsolete.